# setResult doesn't work when starting activity from new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

Setting result from an activity started with new intent doesn't work

I've tried to search for the issue but non-related questions and discussions only were found

first activity: ActivityA: -> lunch mode -> `singleTop`

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class), 1)
```

secondActivity: ActivityB:

```
startActivity(....ActivityC)
```

ActivityC:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, activityB).addFlages(CLEAR_TOP));
```

ActivityB:

```
onNewIntent(intent) {
    setResult(-100)
    finish()
}
```

ActivityA:

```
onActivityResult(){
// always wrong result only! it doesn't return -100 always RESULT_OK
}
```

Comment: Could you show the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

From your `activity C`, you can go back to your previous activity(ActivityB) by calling only `finish()` without creating new `intent`. like below.

In `Activity C`

```
//startActivity(new Intent(this, activityB).addFlages(CLEAR_TOP)); // comment this
// use finish()
finish();
```

And in your `Activity A` do the following.

```
onActivityResult(){
  // here you can check request code 
  if(requestCode == 1 ){
     if(resultCode == -100){
       // process your data here
     }
  }
}
```